# unexpected indent frustration

Tags: python, indentation

I have searched "unexpected indent" the error is pretty self explanatory but for the life of me i can't negotiate it, i've been trying for a day or so and getting nowhere !

the code:

```
    def scrape(url):
    N=10
    for i in range(N+1):
        try:
            return scraperwiki.scrape(url, user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1")
        except: Exception, e
            print "Failed to fetch", url, e
            print "Retry", i
            if i==N:
                raise
```

the error is on the line beginning

```
        print "Failed to fetch", url, e
```

can anyone shed some light on this please ? i just can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exceptions should be before the `:`

```
except Exception, e:
```

Also, you should do this instead as per [the changes](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/):

```
except Exception as e:
```

Comment: Nice, two seconds before I could submit the same thing ;) -- The important thing to retain is that the indent problem usually happens on the line **after** the error, so just look one line above whenever you happen upon this error message (in your case the error is caused by the `print` statement, one line below the `except` statement). Most often this error message is due to forgotten colons `:`